# How to target a file path for windows/mac with actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing an app, and when i am using it in my computer its okay, because i need to execute an .exe script and i know where the path for that file is. But the question is, how can i change it for an automatically way? i mean, i just pass the .exe name and then something find this path for me...

I am using nativeProcess... and i have this:

`f = new File();

 f.nativePath = "C:/projects/SDK/Adobe Gaming SDK 1.0.1/Utilities/ATFTools/Windows/png2atf.exe";`

thats works perfectly... 
I just want to make it more automatically..

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using `NativeProcess` keep in mind you'll only be able to export an exe installer. About paths, I'd embed my exe to my project and then refer to it as: `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('app.exe')`. This returs a `File` object, from which you can then take native path.

Comment: I didn't mean `Embed` command, I meant just copying your exe file to src folder of your project.

Comment: yep, thats what i did...

Comment: thank you, thats easy but i was a lit bit confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a `File.applicationDirectory`. this is automatically find your project root directory.

as follows:

`new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath);`

and if you want target a file path Win/Mac. try this:

```
//Mac
if (Capabilities.os.search("Mac") >= 0)
{

}
//Windows
else if (Capabilities.os.search("Windows")>=0)
{

}
```

Comment: but, i want to find the file path for this file .exe ... i dont know if .exe script will be in my project root directory...

Comment: where is your .exe file? It's somewhere in the root folder or sub folder? `File.applicationDirectory.nativePath` is automatically find your root folder. `File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"png2atf.exe"` or `File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/subfolder/"+"png2atf.exe"`

Comment: in my windows it is somewhere in the root folder, but i dont know where is it located in mac..

Comment: i am a lit bit confuse, but look... if i have this 'f.nativePath = "C:/projects/SDK/Adobe Gaming SDK 1.0.1/Utilities/ATFTools/Windows/png2atf.exe";'  so i would put : var test = new File();
        test.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"png2atf.exe";

Comment: try this: `File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf.exe"`

Comment: it works, but take the wrong address.. it may be caused because i have other files with the same names in different folders?

Comment: what's the mean `wrong address`? memory pointer? or file path?

Comment: the path apoint for a path, thats is my root project path.. but there there is not the .exe ... so if i put this .exe in this folder it will open and execute perfect...  so that line works perfectly: f.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf.exe";

Comment: what i just have to do, its to make sure that i have the .exe file in the projects folder...

Comment: Now, how can i do this for mac and windows?

Comment: so i just need to  add this line 'f.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf.exe";' between the if(capabilities...) ?

Comment: using a this code. `f.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf.exe";` if(Capabilities...) this statement will not be necessary.

Comment: As a side note: `.exe` file won't run on Mac.

Comment: yes, i know, i have the same .exe script but for mac... i will show u how my code looks..

Comment: so, thats what i got: ' f = new File();
        if (Capabilities.os.search("Mac") >=0){
            f.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf";
        }else if(Capabilities.os.search("Windows")>=0){
            f.nativePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"/png2atf.exe";
        }

        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = f;'